# Strictly close Browser window without YES/NO option window.close();

Tags: javascript, browser

I would like to strictly close Browser window with "OK" button instead of "YES/NO" [image]

`<body onload="javascript:window.opener='x';window.close();">`

Comment: If you really want it to be only one button, so not yes/no or ok/cancel, you'll have to make your own popup or find some `alert` hack, as `alert` is the only standard element we have that has only the 'ok' button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function closeWithOKButton(){
        alert('Some info');
        window.open('','_self').close();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That doesn't work with browsers that don't allow scripts to close windows, such as Firefox.